# How do I update a production MongoDB schema without losing previously persisted data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, knex.js

Every time I update a model's schema I have to wipe all collections related to the model who's schema is being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen npm packages like [migrate-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo) or [mongodb-migrations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-migrations). Take a look, probably it's something you are looking about.